# Inno Setup - install files based on feature and automatic update

Tags: inno-setup

We are having the following requirement that needs to be done in Inno Setup. We need to support installation of files based on the password and also automatic update of the next versions either via internet update or DVD

Requirement is:

1. We have several common files for one application
2. on top of that, we need to install FeatureA or FeatureB or FeatureC depending upon a password per feature. Like this we are having 20 different features.
3. The user will install only one feature at a time. But they are allowed to add additional features based on a password.

Above scenario is for running setup from the DVD image. In case of int updates, all the features installed by the customer should automatically be updated without password prompt from the user. It should be done silently.

---

Example:

PC where our software was not installed earlier. Customer using SWVER001 DVD. Install with Feature1PWD => Basic SW + common files + Feature1 files will be installed

Again install using SWVER001 DVD. This time user gives Feature2PWD ==> Feature2 files will be installed. Basic SW + Commonfiles + Feature1 files will be retained and untouched. Main Sw will see both the Feature 1 and Feature 2

User installs SWVER002 using internet update. Here Setup should see both the Basic SW + Common files + Feature1 files + Feature2 files. It should update all the 4 together at once without any input from the user. Silent update would be very good

---

I am thinking of the following approach
1. Create one main installer with basic/common installation files 
2. Then create sub installer per feature
3. Main setup will then call the sub installer based on the passowrd.
4. Main setup will then store the previous features selected in registry/ini file

In case of int update, get the previous feature selected from registry/ini and then do the silent installation automatically without any user input

Any other better suggestions available for configuring above things in the Inno Setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's way easier to create a component per feature and automatically select the component according to entered password.

Something like:

```pascal
[Components]
Name: "FeatureA"; Description: "Feature A"
Name: "FeatureB"; Description: "Feature B"
Name: "FeatureC"; Description: "Feature C"

[Code]

function TestComponentPassword(
  Password: string; Component: string; ComponentPassword: string): Boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := (Password = ComponentPassword);

  if Result then
  begin
    for I := 0 to WizardForm.ComponentsList.Items.Count - 1 do
    begin
      WizardForm.ComponentsList.Checked[I] :=
        (WizardForm.ComponentsList.Items[I] = Component);
    end;
  end;
end;

function CheckPassword(Password: String): Boolean;
begin
  Result :=
    TestComponentPassword(Password, 'Feature A', 'aaa') or
    TestComponentPassword(Password, 'Feature B', 'bbb') or
    TestComponentPassword(Password, 'Feature C', 'ccc');
end;
```

In Inno Setup 6, you can use [`WizardSelectComponents`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardselectcomponents) instead of looking up the component by its name.

---

For update, create a separate installer for each component/feature. Use the same `AppId` for all installers, so that they share the uninstall log.

Comment: Thank you @Martin.
Your solution will work perfectly for new installation. but it won't for upgrade / internet updates as we don't ask for the password. logic should be in case of DVD update or internet update, setup should pickup the components automatically based on the installed feature(s)

Comment: I think we can extend the CheckPassword little bit to check for ini file or registry for the installed features incase of upgrade or internet updates

Comment: Inno Setup will automatically pick the past component for you. So all you have to do is to allow use to select if he needs to add a new feature (and present the password prompt) or if you want to update (skip password prompt and let Inno Setup reload past components).

Comment: Thank you @martin for your reply and your tips on the automatic selection of installed components in case of silent installation. it is very useful. However, we have small complication in that. In case of internet update, we will be publishing the updates based on the feature installed by the customer

Comment: For e.g if we have FeatureA and FeatureC, our main application will detect and send the information to our webservice. Our webservice will fetch only the featureA and C and send it to customer. We have one background downloader service installed at customer place which will get the files and download it and then trigger the setup

Comment: In this sense, how do we split our packages based on feature and then publish it?

Comment: Do you want separate entries in the Uninstall list for each feature or not?

Comment: No. I don't want separate uninstaller for features Only one uninstaller which will remove the main software and all its features completely

Comment: Well, actually, I'm not sure what problem you may have. Just create a separate installer for each feature. Use the same `AppId` for all.

Comment: Thank you @martin. Your suggestions sounds logic. This seems to be the way to go for me.  
How the disk space checking logic will be handled if we create separate installer for each feature? Do we have any 3rd party plugins / inno methods available to detect this automatically ?

Comment: Otherwise, we need to update ExtraDiskSpaceRequired at runtime based on the selected feature(s). Hope this is possible ?

Comment: Before calling the feature installer, we would like to check the disk space requirements and provide upfront warning to the user.

Comment: To be more clear: if our core installer required 1GB of free space and selected feature (based on password or key) require 5GB. Suppose if user select "E" drive for our installation where in only 4GB free space is available, then we should give upfront warning to user and then stop the installation

Comment: Ok Thanks again martin. i will check ExtraDiskSpaceRequired and use it at runtime

Comment: Sorry, I was not correct, `ExtraDiskSpaceRequired` is not display-only. But Inno Setup checks the size on the "Select Destination Location" page only. So typically for upgrades, if won't check again, as that page does not display.

Comment: OK. We can add custom disk space checking logic in case of upgrade then. Do you have any code to set the ExtraDiskSpaceRequired at runtime through pascal code ?

Comment: For that please post a new question.